# Dog-Faced Pony Soldier?

Tags: dialogue

According to the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/biden-jokingly-calls-voter-who-asked-about-iowa-a-lying-dog-faced-pony-soldier/2020/02/09/9e8da478-4b75-11ea-9b5c-eac5b16dafaa_story.html), Joe Biden recently (jokingly) called a voter a "lying dog-faced pony soldier". He attributes the quote to a John Wayne movie.

**Is there such a John Wayne quote?**

Note: A [Slate](https://slate.com/culture/2020/02/joe-biden-dog-faced-pony-soldier-john-wayne-tyrone-power.htm) article suggests there is not and gives its own theory as to where this quote comes from. But I'm skeptical.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Identification questions are now **off-topic**, because they tend to attract low-quality and low-effort posts. The community has decided to *no longer support these questions*. Please refer to this [**meta post**](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions) for additional details.

Comment: This question might be appropriate for https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ , but please first follow their tour and read the appropriate help pages before posting.

Answer (score 3):

It most likely came from a 1952 Western named [*Pony Soldier* (1952)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045041/), in which members of the Royal Canadian Mounted Police are referred to as "Pony Soldiers".  The actual line spoken in the movie is, "The pony soldier speaks with a tongue of the snake that rattles", but it wouldn't be the first time Biden's memory failed him.

There is a spoken line, a voice-over, in the John Wayne movie [*She Wore A Yellow Ribbon* (1949)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041866/) that uses the term "dog-faced soldiers".  It's possible he confused the two or had a "combined memory" where he used dialogue from both movies.